# menu css html5 -> visible and hidden, size of screen

Tags: html, css, ajax

I want to hide the menu only when the screen size 320px is ... Now the menu is always hidden and I need to call them.

when the screen size 320px is, then is ok, when i need to call #main-nav, but by default size must be visible

```
    * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
    min-height: 100%;
    font-size: 11pt;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}

.main-header {
    background: linear-gradient(#3F94BF, #246485);
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: #222 0px -1px 1px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.page-wrap {
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
    transition: width 0.3s ease;
}

nav a {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #283744;
}

nav a:hover, nav a:active {
    background-color: #8c99a4;
}

.main-nav {
    position: fixed;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: linear-gradient(#3F94BF, #246485);
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: width 0.3s ease;
}

.content {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}

#close-menu {
    display: none;
}

#open-menu {
        display: block;
    }

#main-nav:target {
    width: 20%;
}

#main-nav:target + .page-wrap {
    width: 80%;

    .open-menu {
        display: block;
    }
    .close-menu {
        display: none;
    }
    .main-header {
        width: 80%;
        left: 20%;
    }
}

/*Styles for screen 515px and lower*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {

}
```

html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="de" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" media="screen" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <nav class="main-nav" id="main-nav">
            <a href="#details">Details</a>
            <a href="#adresses">Adresses</a>
            <a href="#kontakt">Kontakt</a>
        </nav>

        <div class="page-wrap">

            <header class="main-header">
                <a href="#main-nav" class="open-menu"> ☰</a>
                <a href="#close-menu" class="close-menu">close</a>

                <h1>VIGOUI</h1>
            </header>

            <div class="content">
                It’s all about playing four quarters. I think we played well but the other team played well too. They took advantage of certain circumstances that arose. It’s a physical game.
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need the media query (http://jsfiddle.net/3X8Tq/)

```
@media all and (min-width: 320px) {
    #main-nav {
    width: 20%;
}
    .page-wrap {
        width: 80%;
    }
}
```

That works great for small windows, but for large screens the close button doesn't work.  This is because the close button never worked.  It only works because the CSS is only applying the open :target.  So lets make the close button work.  We have no open-menu or close-menu ids on the page, but you do have CSS for them.

See the HREF `#main-nav` points to the nav.  there is no `#close-menu` id.  Lets add one.

```
<div id="close-menu"></div>
```

And we'll put it before the nav.  We will also add the css for `#close-menu`

```
#close-menu:target + #main-nav {
    width: 0;
}
#close-menu:target ~ .page-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
}
```

Solution: http://jsfiddle.net/3X8Tq/1/

Looking at your css I believe you have a misunderstanding of how it works.  The subclasses in your css only work with [less css](http://lesscss.org/) library.  The `#close-menu` and `#open-menu` don't exist on the page.  I suggest reading up on :target and css selectors in general.

Comment: thanks it works well :) #close-menu:target ~ .page-wrap --> ~ the Aptana Studio 3 showing this (~) as an error?     ul ~ p {  
       color: red;  
    }  This sibling combinator is similar to X + Y, however, it’s less strict. While an adjacent selector (ul + p) will only select the first element that is immediately preceded by the former selector, this one is more generalized. It will select, referring to our example above, any p elements, as long as they follow a ul.